# String is not recognised as valid datetime in C#

Tags: c#, import-from-excel

I have the following line of code:

i am reading ex_date from excel(column sent_date) which is in format MM/DD/YYYY.
sent_date is of type date and in database it is saving in the format of YYYY/MM/DD. i tried adding Datetime.ParseExact. but it gives "string is not recoganized as valid datetime".

```
    string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
    string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sentdate", SentDateString);
```

Comment: Are you sure the content of ex_date is a string formatted `MM/dd/yyyy`? Maybe some values only contain a single digit month or day - or perhaps some values are corrupted in the excel and contains values that can't be parsed as datetime at all? In any case, when sending dates into the database as a parameter from c#, do not send a string, send an instance of `DateTime`

Comment: At which line you getting error? DateTime.ParseExact one or cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue?

Comment: i am reading ex_date from the 2nd row in excel which is sent_date(11/29/2017)

Comment: i am getting error on this line..date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. I suspect the string *actually* has spaces at the start or end, or something like that. (Also note that there's no point in your second line - just use `DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(...);`. I'd also advise you to follow a consistent and idiomatic naming convention - neither `ex_date` nor `SentDateString` are idiomatic local variable names in C#. (Finally, I'd suggest avoiding `AddWithValue` - specify the parameter type and name, then set the value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting error on ParseExact: that means your value from excel is wrong. Make sure all values are correct.

It is working:[see here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rsUjAp)

EDIT:

```
string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();
ex_date = ex_date.Split(' ')[0];
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sentdate", SentDateString);
```

Because you are passing string value in sql datetime column. you need to convert string to datetime:

```
 string SentDateString = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
 DateTime SentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(SentDateString).Date;
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sentdate", sentDate);
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: i am getting error on this line..date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);

Comment: can you plz tell which line you getting error? and can you quick vatch for the actual values?

Comment: ok, then i understood it wrong sorry:( that means value you getting from excel is wrong plz add watch for that and check value. it could be 14/12/2017 so 14 cant be converted to month

Comment: it is 10/29/2017

Comment: Its working for me, can you show image of error and value? see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rsUjAp

Comment: is this right?... string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();

Comment: You can check after adding breakpoint at this line and then quick watch the value you getting or show previous lines of code

Comment: string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();.......for this line it display the value as 10/29/2017 12:00:00 AM

Comment: now i got your problem actually in your input there is time as well. see updated answer

Comment: date = DateTime.ParseExact(ex_date, "MM/dd/yyyy", null); At this line it displays the value as 1/1/2001 12:00:00 AM and breakpoint is not moving forward after this line ..it gives error

Comment: you mean at previous line the value of ex_date is 10/29/2017 12:00:00 AM and at parseexact line it is: 1/1/2001 12:00:00 AM? make sure you using same lines of code. If so then definitely you are getting wrong value from excel

Comment: its working fine @preet. Thank u so much...:).....i have used while(dr.read){code}dr.close();......if there are three entries in excelfile,it is reading them and entering it into database but after reading 3rd entry,reader is not closing ..it is going into the loop and reading fourth entry which does not contain any details.it is taking ex_date(actual value:" ") as empty.. thats  why dat issue is coming...